# C# How to stop a method if it takes longer than 2 seconds?

Tags: c#, timer

Following program will connect to the web and get html content of “msnbc.com” webpage and print out the result. If it takes longer than 2 seconds to get data from the webpage, I want my method to stop working and return. Can you please tell me how can I do this with an example?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gethtml();
        MessageBox.Show("End of program");
    }

    public void gethtml()
    {
        HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://msnbc.com/");

        WebResponse Response = WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
        Stream WebStream = Response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(WebStream);
        string webcontent = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(webcontent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to execute the fetch in a thread, and abort the thread if it takes more than two seconds (via a timer setup/invoke).

Comment: @ashes999: That is a very, very bad idea. **Only abort a thread if you are planning on taking down the entire process.** Aborting a thread should be a last resort. Aborting a managed thread can corrupt data structures arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your answers.

Comment: @EricLippert the way we do it in Silverlight is to create a cancellable BackgroundWorker, which is abortable. Maybe I should have been more precise :)

Comment: @ashes999: Being safely abortable is not a property of a thread; it is a property of what the thread is doing. *Does the thread mutate a shared data structure and leave it in an invalid state when the thread is aborted?* is the relevant question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated above .Timeout

```
    public void gethtml()
    {
        HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://msnbc.com/");
        WebRequestObject.Timeout = (System.Int32)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        try
        {
            WebResponse Response = WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
            Stream WebStream = Response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(WebStream);
            string webcontent = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(webcontent);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fail");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Two seconds is **far too long** to block the UI. You should only block the UI if you are planning on getting the result in, say fifty milliseconds or less.

Read this article on how to do a web request without blocking the UI:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4654/asynchronous-httpwebrequest/

Note that this will all be much easier in C# 5, which is in beta release at present. In C# 5 you can simply use the `await` operator to asynchronously await the result of the task. If you would like to see how this sort of thing will work in C# 5, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/async

Answer (score 6):

Set the `Timeout` property of your `WebRequest` object. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx)

MSDN Example:

```
// Create a new WebRequest Object to the mentioned URL.
WebRequest myWebRequest=WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
Console.WriteLine("\nThe Timeout time of the request before setting is : {0} milliseconds",myWebRequest.Timeout);

// Set the 'Timeout' property in Milliseconds.
myWebRequest.Timeout=10000;

// This request will throw a WebException if it reaches the timeout limit before it is able to fetch the resource.
WebResponse myWebResponse=myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) property on HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to asynchronous downloading of the content. You will stop blocking UI thread and will be able to handle multiple requests easily. You will be able to increase timeout significantly without impact on UI, and can decide upon receiving response if you still want to fetch data.