# XML-RPC timeout?

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

I'm attempting to consume an XML-RPC webservice from C# (.NET 3.5). If it doesn't respond within 15 seconds, I'd like the request to time out, so that I can attempt to contact the backup webservice.

I am using the `CookComputing.XmlRpc` client.

Comment: Do you mean C# 3 running against .NET 3.5? There's no such thing as C# 3.5.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354275/c-sharp-how-to-stop-a-method-if-it-takes-longer-than-2-seconds?rq=1

Comment: Timeouts are the domain of the comms API, so tag it for CookComputing etc.

Comment: Also useful for such a use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370811/implementing-a-timeout-on-a-function-returning-a-value

Comment: In our system, we set a time-out and retry X times, when X = Y, we try a backup service - the only thing to watch out for is that the web service may still process a timed out request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [XML-RPC.NET docs](http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-3-0-0.html#2.4):

**2.4 How do I set a timeout on a proxy method call?**

> Proxy classes are derived from IXmlRpcProxy and so inherit a Timeout property. This
>   takes an integer which specifies the timeout in milliseconds. For
>   example, to set a 5 second timeout:

```
ISumAndDiff proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ISumAndDiff>();
proxy.Timeout = 5000;
SumAndDiffValue ret = proxy.SumAndDifference(2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth to note that this doesn't work with an async model. To do this I would [look at this post as this helped me overcome that problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

For example

```
public interface IAddNumbersContract
{
    [XmlRpcBegin("add_numbers")]
    IAsyncResult BeginAddNumbers(int x, int y, AsyncCallback acb);

    [XmlRpcEnd]
    int EndAddNumbers(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
}

public class AddNumbersCaller
{
    public async Task<int> Add(int x, int y)
    {
        const int timeout = 5000;
        var service = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IAddNumbersContract>();
        var task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync((callback, o) => service.BeginAddNumbers(x, y, callback), service.EndAddNumbers, null);
        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task)
        {
            return task.Result;
        }

        throw new WebException("It timed out!");
    }
}
```